# purescript-argonaut-generic gDecodeJson: 'tag' property is missing"

Tags: purescript

I'm learning Argonaut and I'm able to decode json manually:

```
foo = """{"f":"xxx"}"""
newtype Foo =
  Foo {
    f :: String
  }
derive instance genericFoo :: Generic Foo
instance decodeJsonFoo :: DecodeJson Foo where
  decodeJson json = do
    obj <- decodeJson json
    f <- obj .? "f"
    pure $ Foo { f }
main = either log (\x -> log $ show $ decodeJson x :: Either String Foo) (jsonParser foo)
```

I'm trying to use Generics instead and I thought

```
instance decodeJsonFoo :: DecodeJson Foo where
  decodeJson = gDecodeJson
```

would work.

however, I got `(Left "When decoding a Main.Foo: 'tag' property is missing")`

looked at [Generic.purs](https://github.com/purescript-contrib/purescript-argonaut-generic/blob/master/src/Data/Argonaut/Decode/Generic.purs) but I'm new to Generics and can't figure out.

Do I misunderstand something or how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try encoding `Foo { f: "xxx" }` with `gEncodeJson` - you'll see that the output format includes a `tag` property, which is what the decode is complaining about.

Generic encode/decode is mostly useful when you have it as a serialization format as your app, for cases like this, if you have the `Foo` value provided from somewhere else it's better to write the codecs yourself.